# Do you get any protection from an incomplete vaccine series?

Tags: health

The Hepatitis B vaccine series requires 3 shots and Hepatitis A vaccine requires 2 shots. The last dose in both vaccines takes place 6 months after the first dose, so some people don't get the last dose until after their travels. If you've only received a portion of the total doses required for the full series, do you get any protection? If so, to what degree?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about medicine

Comment: These vaccines are recommended for travel to many countries. Lots of people only get them before travel but do not complete the series because they take 6 months.

Comment: but how many shots do you need is not a travel question any more!

Comment: I beg to differ. If you knew you didn't get any protection from one dose of a vaccine in a series, could that potentially affect your decision to travel in a country that the vaccine is recommended for?

Comment: that is like asking how often should you replace the timing belt of your car. You need the car to travel and if there is a risk to damage the engine, this may change your decision to travel but... how often to change your timing belt is NOT A TRAVEL QUESTION!

Comment: I know what you're trying to get at. But i believe practically speaking, most people think about these vaccines only when they travel to places of risk. That's why there are so many vaccine questions on this site. A timing belt question could apply at any time regardless of travel and using a car isn't a requisite for travelling. However, having immunity from a life or death disease is a requisite for travelling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could hardly be better.

According to Canadian public health agency, 95-100% of patients produce antibodies after 1 shot of Hepatitis A, nearly 100% after two shots.

Though, this does not mean you are nearly 100% immune after two shots

> **Immunogenicity**
>
> In serologic studies of HA vaccines, 95% to 100% of vaccinees developed protective concentrations of antibody against HA after a single dose of HA vaccine, and nearly 100% seroconverted after receiving two doses.
>
> There is no reduction, and possibly even an increase, in seroprotection rates achieved by HAHB vaccine compared with monovalent HA and HB vaccines. Equivalent seroconversion rates are achieved by HA-Typh-I vaccine compared with typhoid and monovalent HA vaccines.

Source: http://www.phac-aspc.gc.ca/publicat/cig-gci/p04-hepa-eng.php#a3

Disclaimer: This is no medical advice and you should consult an authorized practitioner.